# How can I get recent entris to first as deault in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

i'm very new on cakephp.I have 35 tables in my data base and want to edit default index.ctp views to get recent entry first and also in other search results I want to put recent entries first. So, I'm try to edit find() function using 'beforeFind()' callback. I wrote following function and put it to 'AppController', but it didn't work. Is there any error in this code or I put it on wrong place.Does anyone help me to find mistake ? Thanks

```
function beforeFind($queryData) { 
           if (!isset($queryData['order'])) { 
                   $queryData['order'] = array(); 
           } 
           $queryData['order'][$model->alias.'.id'=> 'DESC']; 
           return $queryData; 
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cakephp model attribute

The default ordering of data for any find operation. Possible values include:

```
$order = "field"
$order = "Model.field";
$order = "Model.field asc";
$order = "Model.field ASC";
$order = "Model.field DESC";
$order = array("Model.field" => "asc", "Model.field2" => "DESC");
```

refer [cakephp documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#order)

So in AppModel just define the following

```
public $order = "id desc";
```

Comment: this is almost worked for me, but there is small problem.when i put that in AppModel, there is sql error for ambiguous id field. so I put $order to each model files with change id to ModelName.id (ex: User Model - public $order = "User.id desc";). so it worked. If any one know how to put '$order' to AppModel without getting sql errors

Comment: public $primaryKey = 'id';